# How to rectify this virtualhost setup on Wamp?

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, wampserver

Could anyone please help me with setting up this virtual host on my WAMP server?

I have read through several posts and blogs online and unable to get this set up.

I followed the procedure suggested here: http://www.ruifeio.com/2011/01/30/setting-up-virtual-hosts-on-wampserver/

When I do the above, my server hangs up. Presently I added the following to my C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 tsg.local
```

And I changed my httpd.conf Apache config file with Listen 90 since I am using Port 90

Plus, removed # tag as suggested in the above tutorial.

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I also added the following to my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot “C:\wamp\www\tsg\”
ServerName tsg.local
ErrorLog “C:\wamp\www\logs\tsg.log”
CustomLog “C:/wamp/www/logs/common.log” common
</VirtualHost>
```

And changed: NameVirtualHost *:80 to **NameVirtualHost *:90**

Thanks for helping out in advance!

Comment: The process mentioned in this post helped me finally.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391799/multiple-virtual-sites-with-wampserver?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391799/multiple-virtual-sites-with-wampserver?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server will start fine with the Virtual Host block removed, try fixing your quotes. It looks like you have some "magic quotes" instead of straight quotes - likely from copy and pasting from the tutorial. Try this instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\tsg\"
ServerName tsg.local
ErrorLog "C:\wamp\www\logs\tsg.log"
CustomLog "C:/wamp/www/logs/common.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

You also might want to pick a more standard port to listen on, 8080 or 8888 rather than 90 if 80 is not an option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed it already after boiling my head for 3 hours. Still appreciate your help.